# The set of measurable functions together with convergence in measure is a completely metrizable abelian topological group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a complete $\sigma$-finite measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$,
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

For $\delta >0$ and $f,g \in L^0 (X)$, we write
$$
\begin{align*}
\{|f - g| > \delta\} &:= \{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\}, \\
\mu (|f - g| > \delta) &:= \mu (\{|f - g| > \delta\}).
\end{align*}
$$

For $f, g \in L^0 (X)$, we define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}.
$$

Then $\hat \rho$ is an [extended pseudometric](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Metric_space#Generalizations_of_metric_spaces) on $L^0 (X)$. Of course, we can make $\hat \rho$ into a bona fide metric by [trimming](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3813166/1019043) and [taking quotient](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Quotient_space_(topology)#Definition) by the class of functions equal to $0$ $\mu$-a.e. For $f_n, f \in L^0(X)$, we have $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754273/convergence-in-a-complete-measure-is-metrizable) $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions). By Weierstrass [criterion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weierstrass_M-test#Generalization) for Banach space, we [get](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/789823/1019043) that $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$ is complete.

**My understanding** It seems $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$ is *not* necessarily a TVS because scalar multiplication is *not* necessarily continuous in the topology induced by $\hat \rho$. Take $E=Y = \mathbb R$ and $\nu$ its Lebesgue measure. Let $f_n \equiv 1$ and $\lambda_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $|\lambda_n -1| \to 0$ and $\hat \rho(f_n, 1) =0$. However,
$$
\hat \rho (\lambda_n f_n, 1) = \hat \rho \bigg (\frac{1}{n}, 0 \bigg) = +\infty.
$$

Clearly, $\hat \rho$ is translation-invariant. Also,
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat \rho (f_n+g_n, f+g) &= \hat \rho (f_n-f, g-g_n) \\
&\le  \hat \rho (f_n-f, 0) +  \hat \rho (0, g-g_n) \\
&=  \hat \rho (f_n, f) +  \hat \rho (g, g_n),
\end{align*}
$$
so addition is continuous in $\hat \rho$. We have $\hat \rho (f, g) = \hat \rho (-f, -g)$, so the inversion map is also continuous. Clearly, $f+g =g+f$ for $f, g \in L^0(X)$. Then $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$ is a [completely metrizable abelian topological group](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Completely_metrizable_space#Completely_metrizable_abelian_topological_groups).

1. Could you confirm if my above understanding is fine?
2. Are there some applications of $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: You've miscomputed $\hat{\rho}(1/n, 0)$.  It equals $1/n$, not $+\infty$.

Comment: Specifically, with $f=1/n$, $g=0$, we have $\mu(|f-g| > \delta) = 0$ for all $\delta \ge 1/n$, and $\infty$ otherwise.  So the infimum in $\hat{\rho}(f,g)$ is $1/n$, attained at $\delta = 1/n$.

Comment: @NateEldredge You are right! It should be $\hat{\rho}(1/n, 0) = 1/n$. However, it seems I have found a new counter-example. Let $f_n (x) =f(x) =x \in \mathbb R$ and $\lambda_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $\lambda =0$. Then for all $\delta>0$,
$$
\mu (|\lambda_n f_n - \lambda f| > \delta) = \mu ( \{x \in \mathbb R : |x| > n \delta\}) = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Regarding applications groups of the form $L^0(X,\mu)$ for standard Borel $X$ and a pathological $\mu$ (real valued functions) were the first examples of extremely amenable groups. They also give examples of exotic groups (no unitary reps) and groups of the form $L^0(G)$ for a topological group $G$ are sometimes whirly amenable groups, a property stronger than extreme amenability (due to Pestov-Schneider). I'm not aware of applications were the codomain is an infinite dimensional Banach space, but this is certainly due to my ignorance, not the lack of applications

Comment: Ah, hmm.  I realized the proof I had in mind that $L^0$ is a TVS was for *finite* measures.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you so much for elaboration!